# simple way to randomly subset a raster in R

Tags: r, random, subset, raster

I work in R.
I have a raster (raster_entrop). I want to automatically generate random subset of this raster. The issue is that its extent is not rectangular and I want subsets completly enclosed in the extent.
My solution is to check if there are not "NaN" (corresponding to pixel outside the extent of raster_entrop) in the coordinate of my "subextent" which are randomly chosen inside the extent of the original raster.

```
ext<-extent(raster_entrop)
repeat{
  rnd.x<-runif(1,ext@xmin, ext@xmax)
  rnd.y<-runif(1,ext@ymin, ext@ymax)

  #Test if the sub extent is completely within the "big extent" 
  test<-is.na(extract(raster_entrop, cbind(rnd.x,rnd.y)))+
  is.na(extract(raster_entrop, cbind(rnd.x,rnd.y+0.02)))+
  is.na(extract(raster_entrop, cbind(rnd.x+(0.02),rnd.y)))+
  is.na(extract(raster_entrop, cbind(rnd.x+(0.02),rnd.y+0.02)))

  if (test==0){
    break
  }
}
ext_sub<-extent(c(rnd.x, rnd.x+0.02,rnd.y,rnd.y+0.02))
raster_entrop_sub <- crop(raster_entrop, ext_sub)
```

My question: Is there a simpler solution which does not use a loop ?

Comment: It might help if you also posted a sample dataset and/or the definition of the function "extent". Trying to run your code results in the following error: Error: could not find function "extent"

Comment: found smthg useful here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/random-sampling-of-raster-using-r